# Illegal Argument Exception is thrown while deploying ear file in JBOSS server

Tags: java, jboss7.x

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>{"jboss.deployment.unit.\"novartis-clinpro-ear.ear\".
CONFIGURE_MODULE" =>"WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase CONFIGURE_MODULE of deployment \"novartis-clinpro-ear.ear\" 
Caused by:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYSRV0099: 'novartis-clinpro-web.war' cannot be loaded from a ServiceModuleLoader 
as its name does not start with 'deployment."}}
```

Basically I am migrating java 1.6 version to 1.8 for an application and trying to deploy it in JBOSS server.using Maven to build the codes.

Comment: That looks like a very odd message. How are you deploying your application and what version of WildFly or JBoss EAP are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

Your module-alias in jboss-deployment-structure.xml has to start with "deployment.". For example:

```
<module-alias name="deployment.demoWar" />
```